# PHP backend saves data from other session

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, session

I have implemented a PHP webpage with multiple users, using the application at the same time. In the application the users can fill some input fields and send the data to the backend. The backend makes some calculations and sends it to a MySQL table. The problem is that when 2 or more users use the application at the same time it saves all users input data to the database. Here's an example:

User 1
Input: "this should be written to db"

User 2
Input: "this should not be written to db:

When user 1 presses on the submit button. Data is then sent to the backend file. The backend file then writes the data in the MySQL table. The problem is here: both input from user 1 and user 2 is written in the database though user 2 has not pressed on the submit button.

Any ideas of how to solve this problem??

Comment: Something else is happening.. It is impossible for data to be received without data being sent..

Comment: Can you show us some code to see where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the file before writing to the DB.  Write directly to the DB.  MySQL will handle concurrency and locking for you.

If for some reason you don't want to block while writing to the DB, you can try `INSERT DELAYED` depending on your table type.  Other queuing systems are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store all the users' data in their $_SESSION, and only after the user clicks his save button, you save this user's data to DB.

If you want to store some temporary per-user data, use sessions instead.
They are intended exactly for this purpose.

Comment: You can store whatever you want in MySQL, temporary or not.  Whether it makes sense depends on the specific situation, which Cemil hasn't told us enough about to decide.  Sessions are for session-level data, not just temporary crap.

Comment: From what I read, it looks like he stores result of the calculation into database, and uses this same place for all users. If that is right, then using session instead will solve the problem very well.